# Zabbix's UserParameter returns two value and none is correct

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have created user parameter measure speed of the writes on the iscsi lun that looks as such:

```
UserParameter=write.perf.mon[*], mytime="$(time -p  (dd if=/dev/zero of=$1 oflag=direct bs=4k count=1000) 2>&1 1>/dev/null )"; echo "$mytime" | grep real | awk '{print $$2}'
```

If run from shell with correct values it produce following output:

```
2.78
```

When it is executed by zabbix agent I can see correct command in log, but it shows following:

```
7770:20150921:123734.823 Run remote command [ mytime="$(time -p  (dd if=/dev/zero of=path_to_file oflag=direct bs=4k count=1000) 2>&1 1>/dev/null )"; echo "$mytime" | grep real | awk '{print $2}'] Result [4] [0.00]...
```

And the zabbix collects zeroes.

Please help with any clue why it is so and how it can be fixed

Thanks,

Dmitry

Comment: Try to run command as a zabbix - maybe relative paths (dd, time) are problem. Maybe you need to use $$(command) instead of $(command).

Answer (score 0):

Check what user runs zabbix_agent.
By default this is the user `zabbix`. Check that your chain of commands running with his rights shows the correct value. Most likely you don't have enough rights.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to run your script by user zabbix

   su zabbix &&
   mytime="$(time -p  (dd if=/dev/zero of=path_to_file oflag=direct bs=4k count=1000) 2>&1 1>/dev/null )"; echo "$mytime" | grep real | awk '{print $2}'
2. If is everything is ok try to use $$ instead of $ (mytime="$$...)
3. Check UnsafeUserParameters is set to "on" at your zabbix agent machine. It seems your path_to_file variable contains '/'. Refer to user's manual:

> Unless UnsafeUserParameters agent daemon configuration option is
>   enabled, it is not allowed to pass flexible parameters containing
>   these symbols: \ ' “ ` * ? [ ] { } ~ $ ! & ; ( ) < > | # @.
>   Additionally, newline is not allowed either.